# Auto send push notification from app server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to send a push notification from server when a user complete a task? For example: A todo app will notify on that date with push notification. I want to use firebase and firestore for storing user tokens.
Alarm manager can be a solution that I have found but I don't wanna use it.

Comment: Have you seen onesignal.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use scheduler to send notification from server to your app:
You may follow my working code:

Emplement IJob:

```
 public class SendNotificationViaFcm: IJob
    {


        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            bool isNotificationSent=false;
            try
            {
                var taskToSendNotification = FirebaseCloudMessaging.SendMessage();
                Task.WaitAll(taskToSendNotification);
                 isNotificationSent = taskToSendNotification.Result;

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
                when (
                    exception is ObjectDisposedException || exception is ArgumentNullException ||
                    exception is AggregateException)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception exception) when (exception is InvalidOperationException)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // ignored
            }

        }


    }
```

Call FCM Api from your server:

```
public class FirebaseCloudMessaging
    {
        private static readonly Uri FcmUri = new Uri(
            uriString: @"https://fcm.googleapis.com",
            uriKind: UriKind.Absolute);
        private const string FcmApiKey = "Your Legacy Server Key";

        public static async Task<bool> SendMessage()
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = FcmUri;
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization",
                        "key=" + FcmApiKey);

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(@"/fcm/send", new
                {
                    to = "/topics/global",
                    priority = "high",
                    data = new
                    {
                        title = "Warning",
                        message = "Please start app to track movemoent!"

                    }
                    //to = "/topics/global",
                    //priority = "high",
                    //notification = new
                    //{
                    //    title = "Warning!",
                    //    body = "Please start app to track movemoent!"
                    //}
                 });

                Debug.Write(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                var ck = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
                return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
            }
        }
    }
```

Implement schedular for your time interval:

```
public class Scheduler
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            try
            {
                IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
                scheduler.Start();
               // scheduler.Shutdown();

                var sentCloudNotification = JobBuilder.Create<SendNotificationViaFcm>().Build();
                var cloudNotificationTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(1).RepeatForever()).Build();
                scheduler.ScheduleJob(sentCloudNotification, cloudNotificationTrigger);
            }
            catch (SchedulerException exception)
            {
                Debug.Write(exception.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.Write(exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally Run in from your Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {

            Scheduler.Start();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a tool that allows you to schedule transactional notifications. What sort of server technology are you using?

From a high level you could do something like this:
1) user adds a task in the Android application
2) android application sends request to server to save the task
3) you have some code that runs in some sort of on task save callback that schedules a block of code to run in the future using crontab, celery or something similar.
4) the block of code that runs in the future is an api call to twilio to send a push notification

relevant links: https://www.twilio.com, https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/, http://www.celeryproject.org/, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron